# Rg.Plugins.Popup will not appear on xamarin.ios only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, popup

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup, the popup will not appear in ios only but works fine on Android, I don't know what was the issue occurs

Xamarin forms version : 5.0.0.2083
Rg.Plugins.Popup : 2.0.0.12

Appdelegate in FinishedLaunching:

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
```

Xaml:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">

<!-- Add your design here -->

</pages:PopupPage>
```

xaml.cs:

inherited popup as well

Answer (score 2):

The only reason that would happen is if you don't push it over the main thread:

Try something like :

```
await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async()=> await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page));
```

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have queries